# How can I use the results returned by DSolve in further computations?

Tags: differential-equations

As a neophyte, I'm trying to manipulate the result of a differential equation but I have no idea how to do so.

Here is the equation:

```
v'[t] + (k v[t]/m) == g
```

I know how to find the solution, which is given by:

```
soln = DSolve[{v'[t] + (k/m) v[t] == g, v[0] == 0}, v[t], t]
```

But after that I am lost. Can someone tell me what should I do if I want to use the results returned by `DSolve` in further computations?

Comment: I transcribed the code from your screenshots into your question, please look over it to make sure it's correct. Typically you use `soln` by using it for a replacement. For example, to find `v[t]` at `t == 6`, you'd type `v[6] /. soln` (`/.` is a shorthand for `ReplaceAll`).

Comment: In what way are you seeking to manipulate the solution?

Comment: Note the [tag:manipulate] tag is for questions about the use of the function `Manipulate[]`. If that's what you have in mind, you should clarify and indicate how you want to use the solution in it.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly you mean by `manipulate`?

Nevertheless, here are some common examples users ask about further use of `DSolve` output.

```
Eq = v'[t] + (k v[t]/m) == g

soln = v[t] /. DSolve[{Eq, v[0] == 0}, v[t], t][[1]]
```

> $\frac{(E^{(-((k t)/m))} (-1 + E^{((k t)/m))} g m)}{k}$

The solution is assigned to `soln`, now you can use it for further manipulations. For example,

```
Table[{t, soln /. {g -> 9.8, k -> 1, m -> 1}}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

or

```
Plot[soln /. {g -> 9.8, k -> 1, m -> 1}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking of something like that but my teacher told me to use Manipulate, probably to vary the value of g,m and k and see what happens.

Comment: @GalloMathematico OK! But it was not clear from your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here' my standard workflow for a simple ODE exercise:

```
eqnExample1 = 
 x'[t] == 6 - (6/1000 x[t]) (*NB x'[t]*)
initValExample1 = x[0] == 0
solExample1 = DSolve[{eqnExample1, {initValExample1}}, x[t], t]
solExample1Function[t_] = solExample1[[1, 1, 2]] (* note = NOT := *)
Plot[{500, solExample1Function[t]}, {t, 0, 200}]
Solve[solExample1Function[t] == 500, t, Reals][[1, 1, 2]] /. 
  C[1] -> 1 // N
Print["Note the function is concave down so should approach a \
limiting value:"]
Limit[solExample1Function[t], t -> Infinity]
```

but i'm merely an egg at both mma and ODEs...